# How to use two different iterators on a Linked List in Java?

Tags: java, iterator, linked-list, heuristics, concurrentmodification

I would like to use a linked list in order to perform extractions and insertions of elements, trying out all combinations for a heuristic. Linked lists are more efficient for this type of operations.
Since I would want to try all possible pairs of extractions/inserts, I used two different iterators over the list. This raises a "ConcurrentModificationException". How could I perform this operation efficiently, without re-traversing the list every time, as this would defeat the whole purpose of using a list in the first place?

Here is the relevant part of the code:

```
ListIterator<Integer> it1 = data.listIterator();
ListIterator<Integer> it2;

while(it1.hasNext()) {
    int i = it1.next();
    it2 = data.listIterator();

    while(it2.hasNext()) {
        if (i == it2.next()) continue; // continue right away when the indexes are equal
        it1.remove();
        it2.add(i);
        if (length() < best)
            return true;
        }

    // when the swap is not better/consistent
    it2.remove();
    it1.add(i);
}
return false;
```

Thanks

Comment: If you change the list through one iterator, you cannot use any other iterators.

Comment: Can you use ConcurrentLinkedQueue instead as it doesn't get CME? I suspect there is more efficient way to do whatever you are doing in any case.

Comment: Please google such: www.google.com/search?q=multi+dimensional+linked+list+java and check the results like http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/282327-multi-dimensional-linked-list/

Comment: I have to consider all possible combinations of reinserts, for a specific heuristic. All combinations have to be evaluated. This is meant to explore a restricted neighborhood O(n^2) of a NP-hard problem.

Comment: But you cannot consider all reinserts on a single list, anyway. You need distinct versions of the list.

Comment: Why wouldn't it be possible? It is way more efficient than copying the list entirely (O(n)). This will only swap two elements.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use multiple iterators simultaneously on a LinkedList, however you can with a [`CopyOnWriteArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html)

Try this:

```
List<Integer> safeData = new CopyOnWriteArrayList(date);
// your code, but working with safeData rather than data
```

Comment: Thank you, but this is implemented as an array, not as a list. This means inserts will not be efficient; O(n) instead of O(1).

Comment: @DavidBlinder inserts will be less efficient, but not because of anything you have said. lists *use* arrays internally, but this special class makes an entire copy of iteself internally on change to make it threadsafe - see linked javadoc

Answer (score 1):

If I get you right, you look for a data structure that offers several iterators for manipulating the list. This is technically difficult for the original java.util.LinkedList because it does housekeeping for the current index and this is only possible in an efficient way if there are no parallel changes at unknown positions in the list by other iterators. But, you can easily implement a simple LinkedList that does not do this housekeeping and supports adding/removing through several iterators. Then, an iterator does not know its position in the list, but I bet you do not care. Just use something like this:

```
public class MyList<T> {
private MyNode<T> first = null, last = null;

public MyNode<T> getFirst() {
    return first;
}

public MyNode<T> getLast() {
    return last;
}

public boolean contains(MyNode<T> n) {
    return n.list == this;
}

/**
 * If beforeMe is null, toInsert is inserted at the end of the list.
 * @return inserted node
 */
public void insertBefore(MyNode<T> beforeMe, MyNode<T> newNode) {
    if (newNode == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("toInsert must not be null!");
    }

    if (newNode.list != null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("This node is already in the list " + newNode.list);
    }

    if (beforeMe == null) {
        if (last == null) {
            newNode.prev = newNode.next = null;
            first = last = newNode;
        } else {
            last.next = newNode;
            newNode.prev = last;
            newNode.next = null;
            last = newNode;
        }
    } else {
        newNode.prev = beforeMe.prev;
        newNode.next = beforeMe;

        if (beforeMe.prev != null) {
            beforeMe.prev.next = newNode;
        } else {
            first = newNode;
        }

        beforeMe.prev = newNode;
    }

    newNode.list = this;
}

/**
 * If beforeMe is null, t is inserted at the end of the list.
 * @return inserted node
 */
public MyNode<T> insertBefore(MyNode<T> beforeMe, T t) {
    MyNode<T> newNode = new MyNode<T>(t);
    insertBefore(beforeMe, newNode);
    return newNode;
}

public void remove(MyNode<T> n) {
    if (n == null || n.list != this) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Node is not in the list!");
    }

    if (n.prev != null) {
        n.prev.next = n.next;
    } else {
        first = n.next;
    }

    if (n.next != null) {
        n.next.prev = n.prev;
    } else {
        last = n.prev;
    }

    n.prev = n.next = null;
    n.list = null;
}}

public class MyNode<T> {

private T t;
/**
 * written only by MyList
 */
MyNode<T> prev = null;
/**
 * written only by MyList
 */
MyNode<T> next = null;
/**
 * written only by MyList
 */
MyList<T> list = null;

public T get() {
    return t;
}

public void set(T t) {
    this.t = t;
}

public MyNode<T> previous() {
    return prev;
}

public MyNode<T> next() {
    return next;
}

public MyList<T> list() {
    return list;
}

/**
 * called only by MyList.
 * @param t
 */
MyNode(T t) {
    this.t = t;
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ANY number of iterators on a LIST when you are doing only a read operation.  Since you are doing a remove / add here, you can't use the same list with two different iterators as it will cause the ConcurrentModificationException as you are experiencing now.

What you like to achieve?  May be, people can help you with different options.

Comment: You shouldn't write comments as an answer.

Comment: Agreed.  But doesn't allow me to add as a comment because of the starter status in stackoverflow :(.

Comment: As of two hours ago, that is not true anymore :) The threshold is 50.